# OpenCV vector<point> - No matching contractor for initialization of 'cv::Point_<int>'

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to emplace_back a locally constructed (inside method) `cv::Point3i` onto an object variable (declared as `std::vector<cv::Point>`). Doing so, I get the compile error (not runtime):

```
memory - No matching constructor for initialization of 'cv::Point_<int>'
```

Trying the same thing with a Point2i instead (omitting one of the value I need), the compiler throws no error.

Here's the snippet from the .cpp file:

```
void ObjectDetector::centroids2Dto3D() {
    const int* map_ptr = (int*)mapHeight.data;
    unsigned long steps[2];
    steps[0] = mapHeight.step1(0);
    steps[1] = mapHeight.step1(1);
    for (std::vector<cv::Point>::iterator it = centroidsXZ.begin(); it != centroidsXZ.end(); it++) {
        const int x = (*it).x;
        const int z = (*it).y;
        int y = map_ptr[steps[0] * x + steps[1] * z];

        // MARK: The following line causes the error. Without it, the program compiles fine
        centroids.emplace_back(cv::Point3i(x,y,z));
    }
}
```

As I am not the best at debugging C++, I tend to put the fault on my coding, but I cannot find the problem here.

Could someone points me to a solution or a path toward it?

Thanks!

Comment: `centroids` should be a `vector<Point3i>`, not a `vector<Point>`, and `centroids.emplace_back(x,y,z);`

Comment: You are trying to store a 3D point in a vector of 2D points. There is no conversion from a 3D point to a 2D point, and so you get a compiler error.

Comment: @Miki Thanks! I had tried `vector<Point3i>` as the declared type, but I would still get an error. Using `centroids.emplace_back(x,y,z)` made it work. Though I would like to understand why `emplace_back` takes directly the constructing arguments. Is it because std::vector creates an instance of the class instead of calling the copy-constructor of the class? Thanks!

Comment: Yes............ ;D

Comment: Well! Thanks! It makes sense now. I would think it is better performance-wise (only one call to constructor, instead of two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're inserting into the vector objects of type `cv::Point3i`, then the type of `centroids` should be: `std::vector<cv::Point3i>`.

Also, you're calling `emplace_back` wrong. Its arguments should be the arguments to forward to the constructor of the `Point3i`, i.e.: `centroids.emplace_back(x,y,z);`

Using `emplace_back` will avoid the extra copy or move operation required when using `push_back`. You can find more details [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't read more on `emplace_back` over `push_back`. Just enough so I knew it is best over `push_back`. Should've paid more attention. The difference is clear now and this solution works perfectly.